# Time taken by SerialPort Write

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am using SerialPort communication, in which the requirement is to send data at a specific interval. I also need to calculate the time to send data and delay between sender and receiver.

I have the below code for sender which is in a thread.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
_log.Info($"Started {message}");
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
_serialPort.Write(bytes, 0, (uint)bytes.Length);
stopwatch.Stop();
_log.Info($"Completed {message} took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
```

message is a 20 characters length. I am using Log4Net to log the info.

The output for the sender is

```
2021-03-11 14:07:00,365 [9] INFO  SerialPortSender Started 00000000000000000141
2021-03-11 14:07:00,375 [9] INFO  SerialPortSender Completed 00000000000000000141 took 8 ms
```

On the receiving end, it was very quick and has the log lines below

```
2021-03-11 14:07:00,367 [AspDataLinkTask] INFO  DataLinkLayer Started
2021-03-11 14:07:00,367 [AspDataLinkTask] INFO  DataLinkLayer Completed 00000000000000000141 took 0 ms
```

I am not able to understand why the sender log line took 8 ms when the receiver could almost receive within 2 ms of sender sending data. When I run this code for about 2000 times, I get almost 30 times with this kind of behavior.

Any idea why there is a delay in logging of `SerialPortSender Completed`.

**Update**

I changed the code to use Win32 API WriteFile to port handle instead of .net SerialPort class, it is all good i.e. I see the time calculated/logged is correct.

btw I am running console application in .net version 4.7.2 in Windows 10 64-bit OS.

Comment: Aside: are you sure you want to use [`Encoding.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-5.0) there? The docs state: _"Different computers can use different encodings as the default, and the default encoding can change on a single computer."_

Comment: Your quoted log output looks like the send took 10ms, not 8. So that part of your question is already confusing. More to the point though, there's not enough information here to say for sure why the difference exists. I wouldn't have been surprised to see the write operation take 0 ms, due to buffering, i.e. the `Write()` method returning before the data has actually been sent to the attached device. Similarly, it's not clear that your "receiving end" is _not_ buffering, and thus sees data already there when you call the API to receive it (whatever API you're using). Finally, you say that ...

Comment: ... you saw this behavior only 30 times out of 2000 trials. So _that_ easily could just be thread pre-emption. Nothing in your questions suggests this code is executing in a real-time OS environment (and indeed, that's very unlikely when dealing with C#/managed code), so far all we know the thread got pre-empted during the internal when the `Stopwatch` is running, adding to the total time.